# a set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics) I found the definition of sets in the link.

What does 'well-defined' mean in 'a set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, well-defined means there isn't any confusion about which is which. A well-defined function means there is no ambiguity where you have to ask is $f(a)=b$ or $f(a)=c$ with $b \neq c$. A well-defined set is similar in that if we have two elements of the set we know, without any confusion or ambiguity, if two things in the set are the same thing or not. So we know if $x,y \in X$ we know for certain if $x = y$ or if $x \neq y$.